# Problems installing ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, timezone

I have an USB Ubuntu 18.04 bootable and trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I have try several ways of installation but always getting errors during installation. During the installation, so many errors are shown on the small console (during Copying files... process) 
The errors end with:

```
/* SO MANY ERRORS .. */
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:209: Warning: Source ID 6576 was not found when attempting to remove it. GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
Encryptfs is deprecated
Encryptfs is deprecated
```

Then, the installation stop.
Sorry for by bad English, I'm just trying the best.

Thanks you.